# Set yarn environment variables without using terminal directly

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

We have a CI/CD pipeline that executes `yarn install`. I want to execute `DOWNLOAD=1 yarn install` command without modifying the current pipeline.
I'm wondering if there's a way to tell yarn to do so by using `package.json`/`.yarnrc.yml` files. There's also preinstall hook where I've tried `DOWNLOAD=1 yarn install` but will lead to an endless loop.

Using terminal directly won't do it since I don't have access to the container.

**Edit:** I'm using yarn version `1.22.10` on my local machine, and `1.22.5` on the remote one.

Comment: Is the `DOWNLOAD` envvar something Yarn itself understands, or something understood by a package you're `install`ing? If the latter, then probably adding it to package.json or a Yarn-specific rc file won't help.

Answer (score 2):

`.yarnrc.yml` is only supported for Yarn 2.0 or later. You have to change the file and its syntax to `.yarnrc`. This later version of yarn also won't fallback for `.npmrc`.

Is it possible to set a global environment variable for this pipeline? E.g. add `export DOWNLOAD=1` to your bash profile. Almost all providers support custom environment variables.

After you set up the variable, you can interpolate it in `.yarnrc.yml` (if you update yarn) as `${DOWNLOAD}` as you've probably done already, but on yarn 1.X it needs to be provided in the CLI.

Alternatively, you can use `.npmrc`, which will accept environment variables, and yarn 1.X will fallback to it if it doesn't find the property in its own config.